# power loss during files moving

Tags: windows-10, robocopy

I use Ctrl + X to cut and moving files to another DISK. 15 folers 312 files have corrupted when i check it. it's recommended to using COPY instead CUT/moving ?

because when moving, file transfer faster but if power loss during transfer, it will cause corrupted files. I usually use robocopy with /s /mov , it really faster but i dont know if it have corrupted files if power loss happen

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Moving files is not faster than copy. What's more, it is possible that file may be corrupted in the process of moving. Therefore, I suggest you use copy when you have actions on important files.

Answer (score 1):

First, when power is lost, data that is in the memory buffers is lost, which may include
meta-data about files on the disk. This applies to the computer, but also to
the hard disk which is also a micro computer.
The effects are unpredictable, and no copy 
mode or copy program can protect against these errors.

Second, *move* is not faster than *copy*. The only thing which is faster is that
you don't have to do the extra action of delete when it's finished.

If you are experiencing frequent power outages, I would advise to :

- Get a UPS with a battery so you have the time to shutdown in an orderly manner
- If you don't have a UPS,
  instead of doing *move* do *copy*, and delete the sources only when the
  copy was complete.
  It might be slower, but it is much better than losing your files.

Comment: I disagree with your statement in the second paragraph. While `move` is not always faster than `copy` but if it is done in the same HDD/partition then it is definitely faster depending upon the size of the data. But yeah it might not be the case for this question since he is moving in another disk.

Comment: yeah, thank. I think from now i should only do copy instead moving. With UPS, if power loss, it can automatic put pc in sleep ? and how long it last in sleep mode, thank. With lastest Windows 10 Update, i dont know why it took several minutes to put pc in Sleep. Before that, it only took under 1 minutes or 10-20seconds to put pc into sleep

Comment: It all depends on the quality (and price) of the UPS. The bigger the battery, the more grace time it gives (it is a good idea not to put non-essential devices on the UPS). Some UPS have a USB connection to the computer and software that receives the alerts and shuts down the computer after a time that can be configured.